# how to read from excel file replace string in xml and write into new file java

Tags: java, xml, excel, groovy, edit

A project requires to test web service with the same methods but different host name. I am using Ready API where project is saved as xml file. As there are hundreds of client with different host names that I need to test the related web service. So I am thinking to batch replace host names in the project xml file. Here is the flow: compile a long list of host and other parameters in a excel file, read a row (URL, ID etc.) in the excel file and replace the corresponding string in the xml file and write the xml file with the host name as file name. Then the next row to the same xml file and write the xml file till the end of the excel file in Java or groovy.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion would be to load and parse the Excel file, modify the specific variables inside of templated API xml request, submit it, and then handle the response. Doing this would allow you change the variables inside of one file without having to regenerate all of the files and would provide you with a more agile workflow.

I primarily test Web Services at my company and this approach has allowed us to change variables on a moments notice from the research and development teams, and rerun the functional tests extremely quickly.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, while I need to test dozens of clients api with the same structure. That's why I need to save as a different file.

Answer (score 1):

To...

1. Read Excel files, use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/).
2. Parse and modify XML files, use [XmlSlurper or XmlParser](http://www.groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html).
3. Write new XML file, use [XmlUtil](http://www.groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_printing_xml) and Java file writing classes.

Answer (score 1):

I like Emmanuel's answer, but some time ago I came across a great little library called [Apache MetaModel](http://metamodel.apache.org/). You should be able to use it to both read XLSs and write XMLs, both using a single API. I also concur with Groovy's XmlParser being a great XML tool.

Comment: Dang. Apache has done it again. Thank you Michal for mentioning this :)